# VScode: Stop autocompilation Latex toolchain

Tags: latex, visual-studio-code

I am trying to setup subfile for my Latex notes but I installed Latex Workshop on my VSCode which autocompiles on save, I would like to stop autocompile for the sections.

## File Hierarchy:

main.tex 
sections/ 
Introduction.tex 
Part1.tex

I would like to stop autocompilation for the tex files in the sections folder.

Answer (score 18):

It seems that `"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.onSave.enabled"` is obsolete/invalid now.

I am using `"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.run": "never"` with LaTeX Workshop 6.4.0.

Answer (score 9):

In `User settings` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) change

`"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.onSave.enabled": true,`

to

`"latex-workshop.latex.autoBuild.onSave.enabled": false,`

James-Yu, author of the extension, implemented this feature 2017-11-12 ([Commit on GitHub](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/pull/283/files))

Answer (score 4):

Just go in Settings -> Extensions -> LaTeX

and chose "Never" for "Auto Build: Run"

[image: Screenshots of Settings UI]

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above, one should also make sure that the File-> Auto Save feature on VS Code is disabled as .tex file compilation takes place immediately after saving.

[latex](/questions/tagged/latex)